# Spread bash argument by whitespace

Tags: bash, shell-script

In my-script, "$1" is a string of tokens, separated by whitespace.

how can I "spread" this single argument into multiple arguments to pass to another program for example

```
./my-script2 ...$1  # spread the string into multiple arguments, delineating by whitepace
```

Hopefully you understand the question, had trouble searching for answer to this.

I tried this:

```
./my-script2 <<< "$1"
```

and this:

```
./my-script2 "" <<< $1
```

and other combinations, but that didn't seem to work. I need to support Bash v3 and above.

Comment: But the premise "I call a bash script like so `./my-script1 "$@"` so in my-script, $1 is a string of arguments, separated by whitespace" is false, so actually I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Relevant, but essentially the opposite question: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: @MichaelHomer if you could put your human hat on for a minute and empathize with my struggle at the moment. I was under the impression that "$@" would take all the relevant arguments and put them into a single string, and that single string would be represented by $1 in this context. If that's not true, please ignore that, and start with the assumption that $1 is a string of tokens separated by whitespace. How can I split that up into multiple arguments that can be passed to my-script2?

Comment: Why don't you [edit] your post to show the actual scenario you're facing, showing where your expectation isn't met, and then someone might be able to address it.

Comment: ok that I can do

Comment: I fixed the question, the answer I posted is incorrect :(

Comment: Maybe you want something like `set -f; my-script $1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
./my-script2 $1
```

Unquoted [parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) are subject to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) when [expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.

This is the [specified POSIX behaviour](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05), though some shells (notably zsh) disable it by default. If you've changed the value of `IFS` from the default, that's on you.

Comment: thanks, that works - but I don't understand, you said that when I quote "$@" before calling a script that it won't be all one argument stored in $1 or $2, but it should be, tmk.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to ensure `set -f`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Honestly, who even knows here.

Answer (score 3):

Abstract:
A "filename expansion" safe solution (for my-script2):

```
IFS=' ' read -a arr <<<"$1"
printf '<%s>--' "${arr[@]}" ; echo
```

---

The naive solution of using the variable un-quoted to get it divided into words (based on IFS value) also expose the contents to filename expansion on *, ? and [ (at least).

This specific string works correctly:

```
$ set "a string with spaces"
$ printf '<%s>--' $1; echo
<a>--<string>--<with>--<spaces>--
```

But this string clearly fails:

```
$ set "a bad * string with spaces"
$ printf '<%s>--' $1; echo
<a>--<bad>--<file1>--<file2>--<string>--<with>--<spaces>--
```

The asterisk got expanded into the files in PWD.

#### Here-doc

One way (very often overlooked but also very useful) to get variable expansion without "pathname expansion" is to use a here-document.

```
IFS=' ' read -ra arr <<-_EOF_
 $1
 _EOF_
 printf '<%s>--' "${arr[@]}" ; echo;
```

As explained in the manual:

> If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, … …

Please note that "pathname expansion" is **not** applied.

The cousin of a here-document is the here-string, which makes the code shorter:

```
IFS=' ' read -ra arr <<<"$1"
printf '<%s>--' "${arr[@]}" ; echo;
```

Just remember that (as inside double quotes) the characters \, $, and ` are special.
From the manual:

> the character sequence \ is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \, $, and `